# Same spaghetti sauce recipe for over 30 years

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

I’ve been making the same spaghetti sauce for over 30 years and everybody loves it! But,the last 6+ times that I have made it it tastes acidic. I can’t figure out why.  It’s a very Basic recipe using tomato sauce, a can of whole tomatoes, a can of tomato soup to cut the acidity ( I know that sounds weird but it works)  onion garlic, etc   I use  a little chicken broth and red wine if I have it handy. I always use my Dutch oven to cook it. I add meat balls the last hour or so.  Does anyone have any idea as to why the flavor is different now??

Comment: Welcome! It may sound trivial, but have you changed brands of one or multiple of your ingredients?

Comment: & what's covered by the "etc" ?

Comment: In addition to @Stephie 's comment - have you changed your lifestyle in some manner recently - e.g. given up smoking or drinking, taken up exercise, new medication? Those sorts of things can have a big impact on "taste" and smell perception.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that we had a similar question in the last year or so (about tomato sauce suddenly not coming out the way it had for years), but I'm not having luck finding it.  But you might also want to see the 5th question ever asked on this site : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5/67

Comment: @bob1 : Is there anyone who *hasn't* changed their lifestyle in the past few months?  (I'm a long-haired introvert with a well-stocked pantry who lives alone and works from home ... and even I had to make a couple of changes.  But that was mostly because I was sick for all of February & most of March).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming multiple people are tasting the acidity.

Different tinned tomatoes can have widely different acidity. These seem like a much more likely source for acid than any other ingredient, even the red wine. The soup is likely to be fairly neutral. The onion, garlic (and probably other soffrito) are somewhat alkaline. Can't imagine you've lacto-fermented your chicken broth or your meatballs.

OT but there's some great threads on balancing acidity already.